# scrapy get nth-child text of same class

Tags: css, python-3.x, scrapy

I've attached a picture. 
The problem I'm facing is that getting the first element of same class. I'm trying to get 
`.adxHeader` > `.adxExtraInfo (1st one)` > `.adxExtraInfoPart (1st one)` > `a::text`

I wrote the following code but not working. Any Idea?

`response.css('div.adxViewContainer div.adxHeader div.adxExtraInfo:nth-child(1) div.adxExtraInfoPart:nth-child(1) a::text').extract_first()`

expected output: `الرياض`

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="adxHeader">
        <h3 itemprop="name"> »  درج داخلي للاجار جديد حي المونسيه</h3>

                            <div class="adxExtraInfo">
                                <div class="adxExtraInfoPart"><a href="/city/الرياض"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> الرياض</a></div>
                                <div class="adxExtraInfoPart"><a href="/users/ابو نوره"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> ابو نوره</a></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="adxExtraInfo">
                                <div class="adxExtraInfoPart"> قبل  ساعه و 27 دقيقه</div>
                                <div class="adxExtraInfoPart">#20467014</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="moveLeft">


                                <a href="www.google.com" class="nextad"> &#8592; التالي      </a>
                                          <br />

                            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: What is not working? Is "output: الرياض" what you want or what you get and do not expect?

Comment: @paultrmbrth, Yes, I want this output `الرياض` but getting `null`

Comment: Note that CSS3 does not have a selector for "1st of class", only N-th child under a parent, or N-th "tag" (like Nth `<p>`, N-th `<a>`. CSS4 has [`:nth-match`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-nth-match-pseudo) which would do that (I think) but it's not implemented in scrapy/parsel/cssselect

Comment: You probably need to provide some sample HTML input. And check the source of the page (as in `view-source:`) and not what your browser inspect tool is showing.

Comment: What's your output?, have you checked if there's no javascript changing the html code?, could you post a sample url

Comment: @paultrmbrth, added `view source` content

Comment: Can you provide the `view-source:` extract as text and not as image? That way, the community can test solutions for you

Comment: The `div.adxExtraInfo` is not the 1st child of its `div.adxHeader` parent.

Comment: @paultrmbrth, code snippet added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<div class="adxExtraInfo">` that you are targetting is not the 1st child of its `<div class="adxHeader">` parent. The `<h3>` is.
So `div.adxExtraInfo:nth-child(1)` will not match anything in your input:

```
>>> s = scrapy.Selector(text='''<div class="adxHeader">
...         <h3 itemprop="name"> »  درج داخلي للاجار جديد حي المونسيه</h3>
... 
...                             <div class="adxExtraInfo">
...                                 <div class="adxExtraInfoPart"><a href="/city/الرياض"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> الرياض</a></div>
...                                 <div class="adxExtraInfoPart"><a href="/users/ابو نوره"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> ابو نوره</a></div>
...                             </div>
... 
...                             <div class="adxExtraInfo">
...                                 <div class="adxExtraInfoPart"> قبل  ساعه و 27 دقيقه</div>
...                                 <div class="adxExtraInfoPart">#20467014</div>
...                             </div>
...                             <div class="moveLeft">
... 
... 
...                                 <a href="www.google.com" class="nextad"> &#8592; التالي      </a>
...                                           <br />
... 
...                             </div>
... 
...         </div>''')

>>> s.css('div.adxHeader > div.adxExtraInfo:nth-child(1)').extract()
[]
>>> s.css('div.adxHeader > *:nth-child(1)').extract()
[u'<h3 itemprop="name"> \xbb  \u062f\u0631\u062c \u062f\u0627\u062e\u0644\u064a \u0644\u0644\u0627\u062c\u0627\u0631 \u062c\u062f\u064a\u062f \u062d\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0646\u0633\u064a\u0647</h3>']
>>>
```

But you may want to anchor `div.adxExtraInfo` with the `<h3>` in that case, using the [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) (in other words, the `<div class="adxExtraInfo">` immediately following the `<h3>`):

```
>>> print(
...     s.css('''div.adxHeader
...                 > h3:nth-child(1) + div.adxExtraInfo
...                     div.adxExtraInfoPart:nth-child(1) a::text''').extract_first())
 الرياض
>>>
```

Comment: This way, I need to put the whole div into the selector. Is there any othr way better than this?

Comment: The `s` selector I'm using in my answer is simply to mimic what you have in `response`. You can use the same `div.adxHeader > h3:nth-child(1) + div.adxExtraInfo div.adxExtraInfoPart:nth-child(1) a::text` with `response.css()`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use xpath instead of css:

```
response.xpath('(//div[@class="adxExtraInfo"])[1]//a/text()').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0):

using your snippet this should extract what you want (it also work if you use `nth-child(1)`:

```
response.css('.adxExtraInfoPart:first-child > a::text').extract()
```