# Scrapy selector: get nth-child text of an element

Tags: python, html, regex, xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy selector to extract fields from html

`xpath = /html/body/path/to/element/text()`

This is similar to question [scrapy get nth-child text of same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816164/scrapy-get-nth-child-text-of-same-class/42816537)
and following the documentation we can use `.getall()` method to get all element and select specific one from the list.

```py
selected_list = Selector(text=soup.prettify()).xpath(xpath).getall()
```

Is it possible to directly specify which nth element to select in the xpath itself?
Something like below

```py
xpath = /html/body/path/to/element/text(2) #to select 3 child text
```

Example

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <i class="ent_sprite remind_icon">
    </i> 
    text that needs to be
  </div>
</body>
```

The result of `response.xpath('/body/div/text()').getall()` consist of 2 elements

1. `'\n'`
2. `'text that needs to be'`

Comment: you can do `.../element[3]/text()`

Comment: ```<div><i class="ent_sprite remind_icon"></i> text that needs to be selected</div>```  @Piron the problem is I want to extract the 2nd text element not 2nd element

Comment: Could you put the XML ? First and second text element.

Comment: @Piron added example in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `following-sibling::` to have the nearest sibling (downward) of the expression. For example in this case you want the nearest `text()` of `<i>` tag, so you can do:

```py
response.xpath('//i[@class="ent_sprite remind_icon"]/following-sibling::text()').get()
```

Which gives you the nearest `text()` node to `<i class="ent_sprite remind_icon">`.
If you want to get nth nearest sibling (downward) of a node the XPath would be `following-sibling::node[n]` in our case comes following:

```
'//i[@class="ent_sprite remind_icon"]/following-sibling::text()[n]'
```

Comment: thanks, this indeed solves the problem at hand, can we generalize it for  following n sibling?

Comment: how to use this in css selector? @Moein Kameli